# Caml query for multiple status

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, caml-query, view, caml

I want to create a CAML Query like this

```
(status= waiting for approval && Requestor Manager = UserID)or(status= stage2 && Approver= UserID)
```

Please let me know what i am wrong here

```
 <Where>
  <And>
     <Or>
        <And>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='RequetorsManager' />
              <Value Type='Integer'>
                 <UserID />
              </Value>
           </Eq>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='Status' />
              <Value Type='Choice'>Waiting For Approval</Value>
           </Eq>
        </And>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name='Approver' />
           <Value Type='Integer'>
              <UserID />
           </Value>
        </Eq>
     </Or>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Status' />
        <Value Type='Choice'>Stage2</Value>
     </Eq>
  </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: You might want to download a tool like U2U CAML Query Builder to help you write it. I find it very confusing to write queries when you want to make a "this + that OR another thing + yet somethin else" statements.

Answer (score 1):

**Try the below CAML Query**

```
   <Where>
      <Or>
         <And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='status' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>waiting for approval</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Requestor Manager' />
               <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
            </Eq>
         </And>
         <And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='status' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>Stage2</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Approver' />
               <Value Type='Integer'>2</Value>
            </Eq>
         </And>
      </Or>
   </Where>
```

> **Note:** You can use U2U tool to build your CAML Query based on your
>   requirements, to download the tool check [U2U tool](https://www.u2u.be/software)